# Adding to datastore using EntityManager throws an exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using following code to add an entity to datastore. However, I am getting an exception which I am not able to resolve. Any insights?

```
EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
MyEntity temp = new MyEntity (param1, numOptions, option1, option2, option3);
em.persist(temp);
em.close();
```

I get the following exception at `em.close()` line in above code:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Cannot make object transient since object is new and not yet committed
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:302)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:197)
    at com.vikrams.examquestweb.dao.Dao.addQuestion(Dao.java:34)
```

It's weird that searching for the exception description "`Cannot make object transient since object is new and not yet committed`" in Google gives no matching results. Am I the first one who got this. Maybe I am making some really silly mistake somewhere. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will also need to open a transaction to save any entity.
The basic code to do this is something like this:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();    
em.persist(temp);
em.close(); 
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

Then you should also post howr you entity looks and how it is mapped.